# Largest value of a certain function

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of `n` real numbers `{a0,a1,...,a(n-1)}`
and a binary number with `n` bits, function `f(x)` (where `x` is the binary number) calculates:

```
f(x)= Sum{from i = 0 to i = n-1} (ai) * bit(x,i)
```

where `bit(x,i)` indicates the `i`th bit of the binary number `x`.

For example: `a:={12,10}, f(01) = 12 * 0 + 10 * 1 = 10`

The inputs are the size of the array of numbers `n`, the array of numbers `a` and a binary number `t`.

The question is to find the `x` which gives us the largest value of `f(x)` and also is smaller than `t`.

example:

```
input:
n=5
a=5 8 -3 6 9
t=10111

output:
x=01011
```

My solution was to start with 1s for all positive numbers and 0s for all negative numbers and then try reducing the number until it is smaller than the given number. but that takes a lot of time and I wanted to find a more clever solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that, for any binary number `t` you only have to consider two options recursively for each most significant bit: itself (without the negative numbers in `a`), and one less than its most significant bit (without the negatives numbers in `a`).

For a binary number, such as `4 = 100`, its most significant bit (in this case, the 4s bit) will always be bigger than all other bits smaller than it, such as `3 = 011`. So when considering an arbitrary target binary number `t`, it will be in the form

```
  k     l
/---\ /---\
0...010...01(0|1)*
```

The `k` zeroes before the first one will never participate in the solution, as all `x`s smaller than `t` will also have zeroes in these positions. The `l` zeroes after the MSB but before the next biggest `1` are all available to you. So you can consider

```
  k     l
/---\ /---\
0...001...111*
```

(With negative numbers excluded because they will always be excluded.)

And you can keep making this comparison for each `1` in `t`. Let's look at some examples:

```
a:={1, 1, 5000, 4999}, t:=0010, here you use x:=t
a:={1, 1, 4999, 5000}, t:=0010, here you use x:=0001
a:={5000, 4999, 1, 1}, t:=1000, here you use x:=0111
a:={5000, 4000, 1, 4000}, t:=1010, here you use x:=0111
a:={5000, 2000, 1, 2000}, t:=1010, here you use x:=1001
```

In each example, we're only considering either the MSB in `t`, or one less than the MSB in `t`.

So your runtime complexity is O(k) where k is the number of ones in `t`. Worst-case complexity of O(n) where n is the size of `a` (`t` is all ones).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach, heavily commented to be as beginner-friendly as possible.
Instead of trying to 'improve' the original bitmap, I start from 0 and turn the bits on, one by one, starting from the bit that matches the highest array value (in your example, the '1s' bit since it pairs with the 9 in the array) all the way to the lowest one, unless the array value is negative or the resulting bitmap would surpass the original.

Should be O(n * log(n)) with n being the length of the array, since i sort the array.

```
def bestBitMap(array, original):

    # Empty mask (i.e 00000) in integer form.
    result = 0

    # Original mask in integer form.
    original = int(original, 2)

    # We iterate the array by its indexes from highest to lowest value.
    #(i.e in [5, 8, -3, 6, 9] i starts at index 4 (value 9), then 1 (value 8), then 3 (value 6), and so on).
    sorted_indexes = sorted(range(len(array)), key = lambda e: array[e], reverse=True)
    for i in sorted_indexes:

        # mask for the bit we may turn on with a bitwise OR operation.
        # Bits go from right to left so we invert the index.
        mask = (2 ** (len(array) - i - 1))

        # Here we check both if the number is positive and if the current result masked by
        # the current mask wouldn't surpass the original. 
        if array[i] > 0 and ((result + mask) <= original):
            result += mask

    # We return the results in binary format
    return ("{0:0" + str(len(array)) + "b}").format(result)
```

Comment: this approach answers the question correctly but timewise the power part(2 ** (len(array) - i - 1)) can be quite taxing for large numbers.( it is not mentioned here but the original question says that 0 < len(array) < 10^5 )